# Organising content using Taxonomy and Views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm just starting out with Drupal and I'm interested in how to display my content and organise it in the site.

I can see that creating basic pages I can use the `Menu` module to add them to the hierarchy of the menu, but is this the only way to organise content?

I'm trying to learn the `Views` module, which is complicated! But it seems more logical to me to create a custom taxonomy and then use the `Views` module to display a subsection of that taxonomy.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You should learn Panels too. Panels works very nice with Taxonomy and Views. Try lullabot video tutorial about views, very good.